# how to - org file with file level properties automatically added

Tags: org-mode

I have several file level properties (like #+OPTIONS: toc:nil
) always defined at begin of all my org files. I wonder whether it is possible to make a org template so that all org files I create in emacs will have these properties added automatically?﻿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `auto-insert-mode` for that.  Add the following to your `.emacs` file:

```
(auto-insert-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'auto-insert-alist '(org-mode nil "#+OPTIONS: toc:nil\n"))
```

Comment: somebody also reocmmended with using hook or yasnippet. I see all the 3 options are correct solutions!